# Bash script seemingly stops working after a few hours

Tags: bash

So, this script runs for a few hours, but suddenly stops doing its job. According to top it's still running, but it no longer seems to do anything.

```
WANSTAT=1
LTESTAT=1

tail -f /var/log/messages | grep --line-buffered mwan3 | while read -r INPUT ; do
    if [[ "$INPUT" == *"notice mwan3track[]: Interface wan (eth1) is offline" ]]; then
    WANSTAT=0
    echo "WAN offline"
    elif [[ "$INPUT" == *"notice mwan3track[]: Interface lte (3g-lte) is offline" ]]; then
    LTESTAT=0
    echo "LTE offline"
    elif [[ "$INPUT" == *"ifup interface wan (eth1)" ]]; then
    WANSTAT=1
    elif [[ "$INPUT" == *"ifup interface lte (3g-lte)" ]]; then
        LTESTAT=1
    fi
    if [ $WANSTAT -eq 0 ] && [ $LTESTAT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "All red\n"
    elif [ $WANSTAT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "WAN red, LTE green\n"
    elif [ $LTESTAT -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "LTE red, WAN green\n"
    else
        echo "All green\n"
    fi

done
```

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe one of your pipe buffers filled up or is blocked on either input or output?

Comment: /var/log/messages was still growing?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Watch the system calls with strace -o <outputfile> -p <pid>.

Comment: 1. Probably.
2. Yes.
3. I'm doing that now. Thank you.
4. I'll try that if Cyrus' suggestion doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a few hours, the logging system closes `/var/log/messages`, renames it, and opens a *new* file with the same name. `tail -f`, however, continues to watch the *original* file, which is no longer written to.

Use `tail -F` instead to ensure that you continue to watch the file named `/var/log/messages`, regardless of which file that actually is.

Comment: I will try this, and mark it as the answer if it turns out to work. Thanks!